# Iterate through object properties and update if condition is met

Tags: c#, .net

Currently I have a list, and I iterate through it, and If a condition is met I clear the data (see foreach please).

**Current code but not really what I want, I want to use strongly typed**

```
public class ViewCommonItemVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Data { get; set; }
    public string Bullet { get; set; }

    public ViewCommonItemVM()
    {
        Data = new List<string>();
    }
}


List<ViewCommonItemVM> commons = new List<ViewCommonItemVM>();

commons.Add( new ViewCommonItemVM { Name = "Projects", Data = someListHere });
commons.Add( new ViewCommonItemVM { Name = "Companies", Data = someListHere });
commons.Add( new ViewCommonItemVM { Name = "Schools", Data = someListHere });
commons.Add( new ViewCommonItemVM { Name = "Hobbies", Data = someListHere });
commons.Add( new ViewCommonItemVM { Name = "Locations", Data = someListHere });
commons.Add( new ViewCommonItemVM { Name = "Interests", Data = someListHere });
commons.Add( new ViewCommonItemVM { Name = "Stuff", Data = someListHere });
commons.Add( new ViewCommonItemVM { Name = "Things", Data = someListHere });
commons.Add( new ViewCommonItemVM { Name = "Somelist", Data = someListHere });

foreach (var common in commons.Where(c => c.Data.Count != 0))
{
    count++;
    if (count > 4 && common.Data.Count != 0)
        common.Data.Clear();
}
```

But I want to benefit from the stronly typed, so

**Want to do**

Object

```
public class ViewCommonVm
{
    public ViewCommonItemVM Projects {get;set;}
    public ViewCommonItemVM Companies {get;set;}
    public ViewCommonItemVM Schools {get;set;}
    public ViewCommonItemVM Hobbies {get;set;}
    public ViewCommonItemVM Locations {get;set;}
    public ViewCommonItemVM Interests {get;set;}
    public ViewCommonItemVM Stuff {get;set;}
    public ViewCommonItemVM Things {get;set;}
    public ViewCommonItemVM Somelist {get;set;}
}

public class ViewCommonItemVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Data { get; set; }
    public string Bullet { get; set; }
}


// Here it should iterated trough the object, and after 
// 4 lenght properties != 0, clear the property list
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to remove property from object or do you want to remove all items from list if condition is met? 
If it's second one, you can't remove items from list when iterating it, so what you can do is something like this:
var count=0;
foreach (var common in commons.Where(c => c.Data.Count != 0))
{
    count++;
}

    if (count > 4 && common.Data.Count != 0)
        commons.Clear();

Comment: @Kadaj, I don't want to use list

Comment: [Type.GetProperties][1] will list each of the properties of a given type. Then use [PropertyInfo.GetValue][2] to check the values. 


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties.aspx
  [2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx

Comment: If you are going to do this(Reflection) only for this class then it is of no use and it'll add performance overhead. If you planned to use generics or interfaces or abstarcts and the type you doesn't know in runtime then it'll be great to use. Unless otherwise as I said do not use reflection for an object, for which you know the type at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use linq to solve this problem?

Something like this may work

```
commons.Where(x => x.Data.Any()).Skip(4).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Data = new List<string>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Must use reflection:

```
            void MyClear()
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo item in typeof(ViewCommonVm).GetProperties())
            {
                ViewCommonItemVM common = (ViewCommonItemVM)item.GetValue(this);
                if (common.Data.Count() != 0)
                {
                    count++;
                    if (count > 4 && common.Data.Count != 0)
                        common.Data.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
```

A bit slower than the original. If you have a property which is not ViewCommonItemVM, change the code to check whether item.GetValue(this) results proper type.